# samba login fail, smbpasswd / tdbsam / pdbedit missconfiguration?

Tags: samba, server-message-block, smb-conf

I cannot get to login, running a samba server on debian7, I can't get a win 8 client to browse non-guest folder.
`smbpasswd` is not doing anything on using it with `-a username`. my backend is `tdbsam` and when I try to add a user with `pdbedit -a username` I get this:

```
Unix username:        username
NT username:
Account Flags:        [U          ]
...
```

How can I set NT username?

smb.conf:

```
security = user
username map = /etc/samba/smbusers
guest account = dan
realm = OFFICE

encrypt passwords = true
passdb backend = tdbsam
obey pam restrictions = yes
unix password sync = yes
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but it works now. (Yes I did restart everything a thousand times.)

It must have been either because I removed `guest account = dan` because my normal user to login is `dan` too.
Or it is because I changed the workgroup from `OFFICE` / `WORKGROUP` to `HOME` (tho my notebook is in a domain).